# Помогите выделить из столбца со строками числа

Tags: python, pandas

Никак не могу разобраться каким образом вычленить значения и столбца. Структура выглядит следующим образом
'"type":"something","coordinates":[[[x,y],[x1,y1]...[xn,yn]]]'
Понятнее выглядит на скриншоте
Моя задумка чтобы создать два новых столбца столбца type и coordinates, где столбец с координатой будет содержать в себе среднее арифметическое всех x и y из данной ячейки. Подскажите пожалуйста, я пока новичок и никак не могу понять как это сделать[image]

Пробовал сделать метод extract но не понял как нужно прописать регулярки

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Ознакомьтесь сначала со словарями и списками python, потом уже лезьте в pandas.

Comment: спасибо за отзывчивость))

Answer (score 0):

```
date_patern1=r'([0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{14})'
date_patern2=r'(,[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{14})'

train_geo['ch1']=None
train_geo['ch2']=None

for i in range(0,len(train_geo)):
  train_geo1=re.search(date_patern1, train_geo.iat[i,train_geo.columns.get_loc('g')]).group()
  train_geo2=re.search(date_patern2, train_geo.iat[i,train_geo.columns.get_loc('g')]).group()
  train_geo2=opt = re.sub(r',','', train_geo2)
  train_geo.iat[i,train_geo.columns.get_loc('ch1')]=float(train_geo1)
  train_geo.iat[i,train_geo.columns.get_loc('ch2')]=float(train_geo2)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! похоже, это не ответ, а дополнение к вопросу. если так и есть, то дополните, пожалуйста, текст вопроса, нажав ссылку «править» ниже текста вопроса, а данный «ответ», пожалуйста, удалите. если же это действительно ответ, то постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы.

Answer (score 0):

если отвечать буквально на просьбу из заголовка *"Помогите выделить из столбца со строками числа"*, то, на мой взгляд, самый простой вариант в данном случае - это использовать json, так как содержание ваших "ячеек" соответствует json формату.

используйте json.loads() чтобы получить из строки словарь.

PS. чтобы получать более развернутые ответы не ленитесь включать в свой вопрос воспроизводимый пример исходных данных и пример ожидаемого результата.